# Magento 2.2 admin domain and front domain is different so loaded iframe

Tags: admin, magento2.2, frontend, iframe

We have 2 domain. and set into magento 2.2 as

**Front-Domain** : abcxyz.com

**Admin-Domain** : test.com

Admin section called one iframe from front-end.

Means: on admin call URL of the iframe is

```
abcxyz.com/productid/ID
```

Getting Error is on a console.

> Refused to display '**abcxyz.com/productid/ID**' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Can you please help me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the X-Frame-Options setting in app/etc/env.php

in your case it should be :

```
'x-frame-options' => 'ALLOW-FROM test.com',
```

Instead of :

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
```

source :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/secy/secy-xframe.html

Comment: 'x-frame-options' => 'ALLOW-FROM test.com',
I have used this but now this(test.com) website open for all website. and localhost too. this is not secure for me.

Comment: You should be clearer on what you want, if you don't want that test.com is open to the whole website then maybe you should re-configure your webserver to suit your needs. But keep in mind that Magento advertise against loading the store in a frame `For security reasons, Magento strongly recommends against running the Magento storefront in a frame.`